# how to dynamically set new TreeItems in a TreeView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

My code is overwriting my treeItems in my treeView. See the pic.

When I click in **File >> New Project**  is when the new window opens.

[Here you can see that there is a treeItem with a leaf in the left of the window. When I am just to add a new item and click in **Enter** my first treeItem is replaced by the last one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQGlY.png)

what is wrong with my method?

```
public void doTree(String projectName){     
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>(projectName);

        //the next 2 lines is just to verify eventual leafs
        TreeItem<String> leaf = new TreeItem<>(projectName + " leaf");
        root.getChildren().addAll(leaf);        

        root.setExpanded(true);
        treeView.setRoot(root); 

    }
```

Comment: Because you are replacing the root...?

Comment: But a new treeItem needs its own root, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. A `TreeView` has one and only one root item. Every item in the tree (including the root) has zero or more child items. Consequently every item in the tree, except the root, has exactly one parent item (the root has no parent). Anyway, you seem to have asked this question before.

Comment: I see. I am trying to do like Eclipse does in package explore. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: When I click in New project, it should really be another "file".

Comment: Yes. Again,you have already asked this and it is already answered.